# Equivalent of NSRunLoop under linux (Raspberry Pi)?

Tags: multithreading, c++11, driver, grand-central-dispatch, nsrunloop

OS X has the `NSRunLoop` which just sits around waiting for timers and sources to fire. Then Apple switch to Grand Central Dispatch (GCD) where you have `dispatch_main()` to keep the app alive and a bunch of `dispatch_source_`'s to schedule stuff or to get notifications (from sockets or user actions). If nothing is happening, the app is just idle and doesn't use any CPU power.

Now I want to learn how to write a driver with c++. So I have a raspberry pi (so linux) and once in a while data is coming in from a socket or interrupt.

Instead of polling I want to work with events.
So I am searching for the equivalent of NSRunLoop for c++ and linux.

Though I would also like to learn how something like that is or can be implemented. In pseudocode the run loop acts something like this, as far as I know,

```
timeout = 0
while (true) {
   wait(timeout) || wait for source event other than timer

   loop all timers
      if timer fired
         run timer action

   loop all timers
       timeout = min(timeout, timer.timeNextEvent)

   loop all sources
        if source hasData
           run source action      
}
```

The thing I don't get is the wait function at the top. How do you wait for a source lets say a timer to fire without going into `sleep` mode?

I have found many examples of polling and timers that go into `sleep` mode. But I want to avoid `sleep` and just wait on interrupts or signals or a user generated event like keyboard input on the command line.

Any pointers on how to proceed?

Comment: have you considered looking at [libuv](https://github.com/libuv/libuv) ?

Comment: Thanks for the link. That's a big project (also to understand the inner workings). Not sure I would need all of that? Anyway, still trying to understand what the basic principles are behind the "wait" call.

Answer (score 0):

Probably it's late for this answer but in case someone ends up here, epoll should be the answer.
https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/epoll.7.html